# this.props.children doesn't contain child methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

class Form extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    validate() {
        this.props.children.map((field)=> {
            field.validate();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className={this.props.className}>
                {this.props.children}
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Above is the Form.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import '../form.css';

class TextField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            valid: true
        };
        this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
    }

    validate() {
        if (!!this.props.required) {
            if (this.refs.field.value.trim().length === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    valid: false
                });
                return false;
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    valid: true
                });
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    setValue(event) {
        if (this.validate()) {
            this.props.setValue(this.props.name, event.target.value);
        }
    }

    render() {
        var input = (
            <span className={this.state.valid ? null : 'field-invalid'}>
                    <input ref="field" type="text" name={this.props.name} placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                           onBlur={this.setValue.bind(this)}/>
            </span>
        );
        var field = input;
        if (this.props.label) {
            field = (
                <div className="row">
                    <label className={"col-3 align-r" + (!!this.props.required ? " field-required" : "")}>
                        {this.props.label}
                    </label>
                        <span className="col-6">
                            {input}
                        </span>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return field;
    }
}

export default TextField;
```

this is a field and contains validate method. but this method is not accessible from Form.jsx this.props.children.

Another parent Contains

```
<Form ref={(form)=> {this.form = form;}} className="label-input-group">
     <TextField label="Vehicle Owner" required={true} name="owner"/>
</Form>
```

validate function is undefined and throwing error. this.props.children not updated in the parent after children mount i think. Any way to make it work?

Comment: You need to show more code...

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's a good idea, but you can do something like that :

```
// Form
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.validate = this.validate.bind(this);
  this.childrenInstances = [];
  this.props.children.forEach(field => {
    field.ref = inst => this.childrenInstances.push(inst);
  });
}

validate() {
  this.childrenInstances.forEach(field => {
    field.validate();
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes you're right. It is against the react and flux pattern as well... so will look for another approach.

Comment: If you want to use redux in your app, I suggest you to try [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/)

Comment: Flux is working fine so need of redux right now. but in future projects i may need to use it. Thanks